# NASM "register size specification ignored"

Tags: nasm

I tried to assemble a file with NASM, but it pointed to this line in the file:

```
mov al, byte ptr es:[bx]
```

saying:

```
error: comma, colon or end of line expected
```

I found a [page on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790146/x86-difference-between-byte-and-byte-ptr) saying that NASM doesn't like the word "ptr" and it would be happy if I wrote:

```
mov al, byte es:[bx]
```

instead. So I took out the word "ptr" and NASM is still not happy. Here is what NASM gives me when I leave out the word "ptr":

```
warning: register size specification ignored
```

and:

```
error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

It's a catch 22! NASM is angry whether or not I put in the word "ptr". Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: I don't use NASM but try: `mov al, [es:bx]` or `mov al, byte [es:bx]` ...  also it's been a while but es:bx may not be a valid x86 address, try to use di, `es:[di]` or `[es:di]` ...

Comment: Why isn't es:bx a valid address and es:di is? I can set bx to whatever I want and I can set di to whatever I want.

Comment: It's not about what you can set- it's about what the processor can execute...  I think it is valid though, try the alternate syntax I suggested and see if that works.

Comment: `es:bx` should be a valid combination, but as @GuySirton mentioned, the segment override should be placed inside the brackets (i.e. `mov al, byte [es:bx]`)

Comment: I have some more lines like this one in my code and some of them use ds:cx instead. When I assemble my code, NASM says "error: invalid effective address". Do you thing es:bx is invalid and ds:cx is valid?

Comment: `cx` is not a valid base/index for addressing in 16-bit code. Refer to table 2.1 in section 2.1.5 of Intel's Software Developer's Manual Vol 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it!
NASM is happy if I write:

```
mov al,byte [es:bx]
```

like Guy Sirton said. If I leave out the word "byte" from the instruction, here is what would happen. If the instruction is one like this:

```
mov al, [es:bx]
```

where NASM can see that I want to move one byte, since I'm storing it in al, it won't complain. But, if the instruction is one like this:

```
mov [es:bx],0xff
```

where NASM can't see how much memory I want to store 0xff in, it will give you such an error:

```
error: operation size not specified
```

It's important to know, especially if you are using [this](http://www.websofia.com/2013/10/writing-your-own-toy-operating-system-enabling-the-a20-line/#comment-5917) tutorial, that NASM won't except the regular way.