# Addressing variables (or, what is ML64 generating?)

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86-64, masm, fastcall

I have an ASM file written for X64. It provides a leaf function. The file was assembled with MASM64/ML64.

The C-pseduo code with a signature is:

```
int GenerateBlock(byte* ptr, size_t size, unsigned int safety)
{
    if (ptr == NUL) return 0; /*FAIL*/
    ...
}
```

Here's the same portion of ASM code:

```
;; RCX (in): byte* buffer
;; RDX (in): size_t bsize
;; R8d (in): unsigned int safety
;; RAX (out): bool, success (1), failure (0)

ASM_GenerateBlock PROC buffer:QWORD,bsize:QWORD,safety:DWORD
    LOCAL val:QWORD         ;; local variables
    MWSIZE EQU 8            ;; machine word size

            ;; Validate pointer
    cmp     buffer, 0
    je      ASM_GenerateBlock_Cleanup
            ;; Cleanup will set RAX to 0 and return
    ...
ENDP
```

When I step the call, it appears `fastcall` is being used, which is consistent with the docs. The first two args are showing up in `RCX` and `RDX`, which is also consistent.

But a test case with a `NULL` pointer is producing unexpected results. Here's the test case that's being used:

```
ASM_GenerateBlock(NULL /*ptr*/, 64 /*size*/, 20 /*safety*/);
```

When I step the code, `RCX` appears to be `buffer` (its `NULL`), `RDX` appears to be `bsize` (its `0x40`), but the compare `cmp buffer, 0` is occurring against a value that unknown to me. From the immediate window:

```
buffer
0x000000013f82bcd0
*(__int64*)buffer
0x000000013f62aba8
bsize
0x000000013f14871b
*(__int64*)bsize
0xccccccc348c48348
```

`13f82bcd0` looks roughly like an instruction pointer address (EIP is `13F50D268`). Its does not appear to be similar to `ESP` or `EBP`.

I have a few questions...

- What addressing mode is ML64 using for the variable `buffer`?
- Where is the value of the variable `buffer` coming from?
- Why is `ML64` ***not*** using `ECX` for the variable `buffer`?
- How can I fix this?

---

The same code, shortened to 32-bits, assembles and executes fine. However, ML puts `buffer` and `bsize` on the stack and addresses them relative to `EBP`.

I also tried changing to `cmp QWORD PTR buffer, 0`, but it did not help.

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From the disassembly in the final screenshot,

```
cmp  buffer, 0
```

is assembling to

```
cmp  qword ptr [buffer], 0   # memory operand.  rip-relative?  or stack-relative?  Not enough insn bytes for an absolute 32bit address
```

instead of

```
cmp  RCX, 0
```

So the assembly syntax you're using still declares `buffer` as a symbol or memory offset or something, not as an alias for a register.  And yes, the x86-64 Windows ABI uses a register calling convention (unfortunately a different one from Linux).  I guess it's similar to the 32bit `fastcall` ABI.  [Agner Fog](http://agner.org/optimize/) has a doc explaining the various calling conventions for 32 and 64bit OSes.

---

Note that cmp with immediate zero is almost always a worse choice than `test rcx, rcx`.  Shorter insn encoding, and still macro-fuses with a following `jcc` on Intel and AMD.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Do you know how I can fix this? MASM/MASM64 has an [`ALIAS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b07c5b4f.aspx), but it does not work under MASM64/ML64. See [A2008 errors when porting from ML (X86) to ML64 (X64)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33118452) The best I can tell, MASM64/ML64 is nearly useless for symbolic development (unlike MASM/ML). All it does is share the same name with MASM (which is a disgrace to MASM, since its a very nice tool).

Comment: @jww: sorry, no clue.  I don't use MSVC, only yasm and GNU as.  I haven't done much with macro stuff even in yasm.  The link someone posted on your other recent question made it sound like MSVC just dropped support for turning stuff like `IF EAX == 1` into actual insns for 64bit.  You can save an instruction sometimes by doing `cmp eax, 1`, and then `jb` for == 0 and `je` for ==1.  So that saves a few insn bytes, and a uop on CPUs that can't macro-fuse two compare-and-branch pairs in the same block of insns.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I fix this?

I can't answer some of the questions, but I know how to fix it. Below, and underlying requirement is the same source code work for both X86 (MASM/ML) and X64 (MASM64/ML64) with minimal changes.

Here was the original C function signature:

```c
int GenerateBlock(byte* ptr, size_t size, unsigned int safety)
```

Under X86 MASM, relative addressing is used, and the ASM code would look as follows:

```masm
;; Base relative (in): byte* buffer
;; Base relative (in): size_t bsize
;; Base relative (in): unsigned int safety

ASM_GenerateBlock PROC buffer:DWORD,bsize:DWORD,safety:DWORD
    LOCAL val:DWORD         ;; local variables
    MWSIZE EQU 4            ;; machine word size

            ;; Validate pointer
    cmp     buffer, 0
    je      MSC_ASM_GenerateBlock_Cleanup    
    ...

    ;; Write byte to buffer from AL
    mov     BYTE PTR [buffer], al
    inc     buffer
    ...
```

For X64 with `fastcall`, a few minor hacks are required:

```masm
;; RCX (in): byte* buffer
;; RDX (in): size_t bsize
;; R8d (in): unsigned int safety

ASM_GenerateBlock PROC bufferX:QWORD,bsizeX:QWORD,safetyX:DWORD
    LOCAL val:QWORD         ;; local variables
    MWSIZE EQU 8            ;; machine word size

            ;; Fastcall workaround
    buffer EQU ecx
    bsize  EQU edx
    safety EQU r8d

            ;; Validate pointer
    cmp     buffer, 0
    je      MSC_ASM_GenerateBlock_Cleanup    
    ...

            ;; Write byte to buffer from AL
    mov     BYTE PTR [buffer], al
    inc     buffer
    ...
```

Above, two fixes occurred. First were the names of the variables in the procedure prototype. `Buffer` was changed to `bufferX`, etc. Second `EQU` was used like a C-language `#define` to equate `buffer` to `ecx`.