# What is the option for MASM pointer PTR in NASM

Tags: assembly, nasm, masm

there is an error when i run following MASM command in NASM environment:

```
MOV BYTE PTR [DI-02H],0FH
```

it gives one error and one warning message:

```
warning: 'PTR' is not a NASM keyword [-w+ptr]
error: symbol 'PTR' not defined
```

here i want to know that what is NASM option for 'PTR' of MASM.

Comment: just remove PTR: `mov BYTE [DI-02h],0FH`

Comment: assembly language is defined by the assembler, the tool, not the target (x86), so you need to write code for the programming (assembly) language that matches the tool.  (or ask the tool if supported to use a different programming language)

Comment: Do you have a bunch of pre-existing MASM code?  If you only fix syntax errors like this, it will assemble but then not work if you ever have code like `mov eax, symbol`.  In NASM, that's a mov-immediate of the address; in MASM it's a load.  If you were careful to always use `mov eax, [symbol]` in your MASM code, that will mean the same thing in NASM so you might be ok.  If you don't have a bunch of existing code, write it in NASM syntax in the first place.

Comment: See [also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13791007/774575).

Answer (score 5):

A limited amount of MASM compatibility can be enabled using the

```
%use masm
```

directive.  Among other features, this enables a MASM-like `PTR` keyword.

Refer to the [manual](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc6.html#section-6.5) for details.