# What is the meaning of "ptr" in assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, nasm, cpu-registers

Since [si] in brackets is like the value at the address si like the *si in C

and since offset si is like &si

what about **ptr** in

```
mov dword ptr [si], ax
```

?

Comment: Did you try searching before asking? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41562732/in-assembly-what-does-ptr-stand-for

Comment: Yes but I didn't unstand what is written

Comment: There must be several thousands of x86 assembly tutorials, references and general documentation all over the Internet. What have you been using or reading? What about their description of it don't you understand?

Comment: Try rephrasing your question to articulate what it is you don't understand about that answer, including answers to other questions that are linked to by that question, or any other material that you have read but didn't understand. Otherwise, your question is essentially a duplicate and will either be closed or will receive answers that you also don't understand.

Comment: The answer indicated by @paddy is very clear, it defines the size of the data pointed by `[si]`. As per C equivalent you can read it as `*((DWORD_PTR *)si)`.

Comment: By the way, `dword` indicates that you want to copy all 32 bits, but `ax` is only a 16-bit register. Don't you mean `eax` for the register? Or possibly `word` instead of `dword`?

Comment: If you do not tell what specifically you don't understand, it is unlikely that you will get different answers than before with identical questions.

Comment: Hmm. If you didn't understand [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987876/what-does-dword-ptr-mean), then you should probably start learning what a microprocessor is and how microprocessor instructions work in general.

Comment: See also [x86, difference between BYTE and BYTE PTR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13790146/555045)

Comment: You tagged nasm but nasm syntax has no `ptr`.

Comment: `ptr` is a veiled appreciation of very active and helpful SO user @PeterCordes. (`ptr` is pronounced Peter.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a concrete example:

Assuming this memory situation (all numbers in hexadecimal), each box represents one byte:

```
Address   Memory content
          +---------+
00000000  |   11    |
          +---------+
00000001  |   22    |
          +---------+
00000002  |   33    | <--- si (= 00000002) points here
          +---------+
00000003  |   44    |
          +---------+
00000004  |   55    |
          +---------+
00000005  |   66    |
          +---------+
00000006  |   77    |
          +---------+
```

- After the instruction: `mov eax, dword ptr [si]`, `eax` contains `66554433`.
- After the instruction: `mov eax, word ptr [si]`, `ax` (16 low bits of `eax`) contains `4433`.
- After the instruction: `mov eax, byte ptr [si]`, `al` (8 low bits of `eax`) contains `33`.

---

- `dword ptr [x]` means: we want to read/write a double word (4 bytes) from/to the memory address contained in `x`.
- `word ptr [x]` means: we want to read/write a word (2 bytes) from/to the memory address contained in `x`memory adddre.
- `byte ptr [x]` means: we want to read/write a single byte from/to the memory address contained in `x`.

Now you may ask why we need to put `dword ptr` and not just `dword`. It's just a convention.

Comment: `mov eax, word ptr [si]` and `mov eax, byte ptr [si]` aren't valid instructions. `mov ax, word ptr [si]` and `mov al, byte ptr [si]` are. In fact MASM/TASM/JWASM can infer the size of the memory operand from the size of the register so `byte ptr` and `word ptr` in these cases isn't needed. The place the sizes are needed are when moving immediates (as an example) to  memory as the size can't usually be inferred from the immediate itself. Ie: `mov [si], 1` Is 1 a byte or a word? We use `mov byte ptr [si], 1` or `mov word ptr [si]`

Comment: The question is tagged with [nasm]. NASM doesn't support `PTR` because `PTR` (just like `OFFSET`) is completely redundant. `DWORD` or any other size specifier is useful in all those cases pointed out above, but `PTR` has no purpose. It was a MASM thing to make assembly look more like a high-level language. Just like `OFFSET` was a thing because they wanted automatic dereference of symbols. NASM took a much more modern approach and doesn't need either. I think this answer failed to address OP's question but then again, the question is a duplicate and there's no point answering it.

Comment: @MargaretBloom op stated he didn't understand the other answers, so I made a concrete example. And op probably wrongfully tagged NASM.